# Hide Toolbar Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What are various ways to hide a toolbar using jquery mobile. Ideally I would like to hide the toolbar above the header when no focus is on it. I started a fiddle with the basic layout

```
    <div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">Whatever</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DMUwp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to hide the **navbar** when you click on the header:

```
    $("div[data-role=header]").on("click", function () {
        $("div[data-role=navbar]").slideToggle(200);
    });

    $("div[data-role=navbar]").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/DMUwp/4/)**.

The other one could be to use **data-position="fixed"** and **data-fullscreen="true"** provided by the library which will hide/show your **navbar** at the bottom of the page when clicking/touching somewhere on the screen.

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/DMUwp/7/)**.

---

**EDIT**

For the first one there might be some problems when loading pages, so to avoid this issue you could take out the **navbar** from the **header** and put it above it like this:

```
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a.html">Settings</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="b.html">Whatever</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Hide the Toolbar</h1>
    </div>
```

And then adding this js code:

```
    $("div[data-role=header]").on("click", function () {
        $("div[data-role=navbar]").slideToggle(200);
    });
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/DMUwp/8/)**.